Extreme Switch Creating Mirror Port
I am deploying an IDS to an environment with extreme switches and the IDS needs to have a mirror port configured on the switch it is connected to. I currently am testing the deployment on an Extreme Summit x440-48t switch. I have factory reset the switch and it seems to be in Slot-2 (don't know if that is relevant or not.)
The command I found in the documentation is: Create mirror
* Slot-2 Stack.6 # create mirror
                           ^
%% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

I have no idea why it is throwing that error. Does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.
Not sure if this helps, but I will included the OS version below. Thank you for your input.
* Slot-2 Stack.5 # show version  

Slot-1      :
Slot-2      : 800473-00-08 1248G-00231 Rev 8.0 BootROM: 2.0.1.7    IMG: 15.2.1.5  
Slot-3      :  
Slot-4      :  
Slot-5      :
Slot-6      :
Slot-7      :  
Slot-8      :  
  
Image   : ExtremeXOS version 15.2.1.5 v1521b5 by release-manager
          on Fri Aug 17 17:23:25 EDT 2012  
BootROM : 2.0.1.7  
Diagnostics : 5.6  


“%% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.” - Suggests a configuration or command syntax problem.
